# CSS transform translate absolutely

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a bunch of children elements that are absolutely positioned in the parent container. I'd like to move some of them to a position relative to their parent container, only with CSS transforms. Is this possible? It seems that CSS translate can only do absolute distances.

Here is a [setup jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2LXM/4/). I'd like the class "center" to make both inner divs to appear in the center with a CSS transform.

The requirement to use CSS transform is because this is an animated transition, and I want the hardware acceleration to kick-in, which won't happen if left/top are used.

I can muck with the HTML markup.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide a short code example and a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I posted an example JSFiddle to illustrate.

Comment: Not possible with `transform` sans javascript to calculate offset distances, I'm afraid.

Comment: One way I found to do this is to use viewport units in transforms, like `vh` and `vw`. `50vw` is 50% of the page. Browser support isn't great though.

Answer (score 0):

try this one http://jsfiddle.net/GrdmL/
you have to change css Little bit because if u have applied some property with help of #id selector you cant modified these property with help of .class selector

hope this will solve your problem for any query post a comment.

Comment: As stated in the question, only transform can be used. The "left" property is not accelerated by the GPU and lags when animating many layers.